# How we resolve Mysql Enterprise online backup error with "CORRUPT LOG RECORD FOUND" log error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, backup, error-log

I have configured my production MySQL database with MySQL Enterprise "online Backup" option. The configuration was went through successfully. When the assigned scheduler is try to take backup then i am getting below mention log error from MySQL database.

Everything is OK, like MySQL tables because this is my production database.
I have 44 tables in MySQL database and most of the table is in `INNODB` engine and also there is `MyISAM` engines.

```
MySQL Enterprise Backup version 3.11.1 Windows-6.0-x86 [Tue 11/04/2014 ] 
Copyright (c) 2003, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.



mysqlbackup: INFO: Starting with following command line ...
 C:\MySQL Backup\meb-3.11.1-windows-x86-32bit\meb-3.11.1-windows-x86-32bit\bin\mysqlbackup.exe 
        --defaults-file=C:\MySQL Backup\80db2ec0-a3df-11e4-bceb-4c72b9719f9c.cnf 
        --backup-dir=C:\MySQL Backup\Fullbackup\2015-01-24_21-15-00 
        --show-progress=stdout backup 

 mysqlbackup: INFO: 
 mysqlbackup: INFO: MySQL server version is '5.7.5-m15-log'.
 mysqlbackup: INFO: Got some server configuration information from running server.

IMPORTANT: Please check that mysqlbackup run completes successfully.
           At the end of a successful 'backup' run mysqlbackup
           prints "mysqlbackup completed OK!".

150124 21:15:01 mysqlbackup: INFO: MEB logfile created at C:\MySQL Backup\Fullbackup\2015-01-24_21-15-00\meta\MEB_2015-01-24.21-15-01_backup.log

--------------------------------------------------------------------
                       Server Repository Options:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  datadir = C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\
  innodb_data_home_dir = 
  innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
  innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\
  innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
  innodb_log_file_size = 50331648
  innodb_page_size = 16384
  innodb_checksum_algorithm = crc32
  innodb_undo_directory = C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\
  innodb_undo_tablespaces = 0
  innodb_undo_logs = 128

--------------------------------------------------------------------
                       Backup Config Options:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  datadir = C:\MySQL Backup\Fullbackup\2015-01-24_21-15-00\datadir
  innodb_data_home_dir = C:\MySQL Backup\Fullbackup\2015-01-24_21-15-00\datadir
  innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
  innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\MySQL Backup\Fullbackup\2015-01-24_21-15-00\datadir
  innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
  innodb_log_file_size = 50331648
  innodb_page_size = 16384
  innodb_checksum_algorithm = crc32
  innodb_undo_directory = C:\MySQL Backup\Fullbackup\2015-01-24_21-15-00\datadir
  innodb_undo_tablespaces = 0
  innodb_undo_logs = 128

 mysqlbackup: INFO: Unique generated backup id for this is 14221143009241185

 mysqlbackup: INFO: Creating 14 buffers each of size 16777216.
150124 21:15:03 mysqlbackup: INFO: Full Backup operation starts with following threads
        1 read-threads    6 process-threads    1 write-threads
150124 21:15:03 mysqlbackup: INFO: System tablespace file format is Antelope.
150124 21:15:03 mysqlbackup: INFO: Starting to copy all innodb files...
 mysqlbackup: INFO: Could not find binlog index file. binlogs will not be copied for this backup.
 Point-In-Time-Recovery will not be possible.
 If this is online backup then server may not have started with --log-bin.
 You may specify its location with --log-bin-index option.
Progress: 0 of 111 MB; state: Copying system tablespace
150124 21:15:04 mysqlbackup: INFO: Found checkpoint at lsn 33399309.
150124 21:15:04 mysqlbackup: INFO: Starting log scan from lsn 33399296.
150124 21:15:04 mysqlbackup: INFO: Copying log...
150124 21:15:04 mysqlbackup: INFO: Copying C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\ibdata1 (Antelope file format).
InnoDB: ############### CORRUPT LOG RECORD FOUND
InnoDB: Log record type 56, space id 0, page number 0
InnoDB: Log parsing proceeded successfully up to 33399309
InnoDB: Previous log record type 0, is multi 0
InnoDB: Recv offset 0, prev 0
InnoDB: Hex dump of corrupt log starting 100 bytes before the start
InnoDB: of the previous log rec,
InnoDB: and ending 100 bytes after the start of the corrupt rec:
 len 200; hex 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0008b000000a011000000000000000000102000001020000de31c1800000004380000000001fda20d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000; asc                                                                                                     8                                                                                                   ;
InnoDB: WARNING: the log file may have been corrupt and it
InnoDB: is possible that the log scan did not proceed
InnoDB: far enough in recovery! Please run CHECK TABLE
InnoDB: on your InnoDB tables to check that they are ok!
InnoDB: If mysqld crashes after this recovery, look at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
150124 21:15:04 mysqlbackup: ERROR: FOUND CORRUPT LOG: cannot continue!
Progress: 16 of 111 MB; state: Copying system tablespace

mysqlbackup failed with errors!
```

I am unable to find out the exact error from my  MySQL error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer to my Service Request related to the same problem from the Oracle Support.

"This is a known problem, MySQL Server 5.7 is not in GA yet and currently MEB is not supporting 5.7 versions. Developers are working on it".

Comment: In place of MySQL Server 5.7.5, i had installed 5.6.26 - log mysql community server and able to take "online Backup" as well as "Incremental backup" .